# Delphi 12 - "F2051 the unit data.sqlExpr was compiled with a different version of FreeAndNil" when following Embarcadero's mobile tutorial

Tags: android, delphi, fatal-error, datasnap, delphi-12-athens

When I try to follow [Embarcadero's tutorial](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Connecting_to_an_Enterprise_Database_from_a_Mobile_Client_(iOS_and_Android)) for creating an Android app that connects to a Datasnap server with Delphi 12, I get this fatal error:

> F2051 the unit data.sqlExpr was compiled with a different version of FreeAndNil

[image]

Could someone help?

Yes, the tutorial has worked for me in an older version (I don't remember which one). The Delphi installation is freshly tested on Windows 10 and 11, and Delphi can compile other kinds of projects for Android, and the described tutorial on Windows x64, but not the described tutorial for Android.

I tried reinstalling Delphi, changing the computer, uninstalling and installing a previous version of Delphi, checking for any updates, posting a case at Delphi, even with Delphi-Praxis forum. And now I am here.

Comment: Given the error message, I doubt it has anything to do with the tutorial. You have either an IDE library path or project search path such that the compiler is finding a unit (Data.SqlExpr) that is incompatible with Delphi 12.

Comment: thank you
yes the tutorial have worked with me in one older version (didn't rememeber wich one) 
the delphi installation is fresh tested on windows 10 and 11, and delphi can compile other kind of project for android, and the described tutorial on windows x64,
but not the described tutorial for android

Comment: Please read David's message carefully

Comment: I'm not sure but I suspect this may be due the fact that Delphi removed ARC (Advanced Reference Counting) support for mobile platforms. Why? Looking at `Data.SqlExpr` source code I can see that it was written with ARC support in mind due to the fact that it contains many weak references when defining fields.

Comment: I agree with DaveNottage. This is the kind of error one would typically get when the compiler accidentally tries to recompile source code units instead of using their pre-existing binary DCUs/LIBs, which is usually the result of a bad configuration.

Comment: @SilverWarior It has nothing to do with ARC. It was compiled with different Delphi version. All major versions are incompatible. You cannot use unit (dcu) compiled with one version in another different version. That was always the case, ARC or no ARC. When it comes to having weak references in that unit you will also find them in all other RTL and FMX code as they were not removed. They simply have no effect on non ARC compilers. Like Remy and Dave said, the problem is bad configuration and even the same version can have conflicts if different compiler directives where used for compiling.

Comment: thank you for the comments, each one is very benific

Comment: thank you for the comments
DalijaPrasnikar, it could not be a version problem because even a new project on new windows installation get the same error, not just a saved project
the same project works when debugged on windows, IOs, MacOs  but not on Android
@DaveNottage the tutorial looks good because it worked for me once not just once i developed a full solution based on that tutorial, and for the compatibility Data.SqlExpr why Embarcadero do such thing? i tested also with Delphi 10 an 11 and i have had the same problem
could someone teste this tutorial

Comment: It might help to put the test project that you created somewhere (in a .zip file) so someone else can compile it, rather than expecting others to spend time creating one for you

Comment: thank you @DaveNottage for the advise, and hear is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xpzwRHHeOvzOZkuuzxYzZwcPJXGLjXML/view?usp=sharing) of a saved project that anyone could open in Delphi and compile.
It is a group project of a REST server and a Mobile client the problem appear when trying to compile for Android in the unit ClientClassUnit1.pass line 10 on "Datasnap.DSProxyRest"

Comment: You didn't include the mobile client project in that archive

Comment: hello,
@DaveNottage, it wase a mistakes, the [fille](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xpzwRHHeOvzOZkuuzxYzZwcPJXGLjXML/view?usp=drive_link) is uploaded again.
Thank you

Comment: The mobile client app (Project1) compiles for me for Android 64-bit without error, using Delphi 12